# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I always get this error when I try to run my program. It is frustrating because this program is due tomorrow. This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at trial.connection.returndata(connection.java:22)
at trial.search.jTextField1KeyReleased(search.java:150)
at trial.search.access$000(search.java:21)
at trial.search$1.keyReleased(search.java:100)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6466)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2828)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at trial.connection.returndata(connection.java:22)
at trial.search.jTextField1KeyReleased(search.java:150)
at trial.search.access$000(search.java:21)
at trial.search$1.keyReleased(search.java:100)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6466)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2828)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is the whole code from the frame that I'm currently working on:

```
package trial;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class search extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static Connection connection;
static String url;
static Statement st;
static ResultSet rs;

Connection myconnection;
Statement stStatement;
Statement stLogin;
ResultSet rsData;
PreparedStatement psPreparedStatement;

/**
 * Creates new form search
 */
public search() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    medrec_table = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    medrec_table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Student ID", "Date", "Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Ailment", "Remarks"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(medrec_table);

    jLabel1.setText("Search for Medical Records");

    jTextField1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            jTextField1KeyReleased(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 678, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(21, 21, 21))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 145, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap())))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
public ResultSet consulta(String sql) throws SQLException
{
    try {
        rsData=stStatement.executeQuery(sql); 
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return rsData;
}
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
try {

    connection c = new connection();
    DefaultTableModel T;
    T= c.returndata("Select * From medrec Where student_no=?");
medrec_table.setModel(T);
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(medrec_table);
    } 

 catch(HeadlessException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        //  Logger.getLogger(log.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);     
     }
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new search().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTable medrec_table;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: The exception is telling you that `returndata` method in `connection` class is unimplemented and throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Check that method.

Comment: check existing similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861336/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-not-supported-yet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961188/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception

Comment: There are some other problems in your code: 1) `KeyListener`'s are rarely an option when working with Swing. For `JTextField` we typically use `DocumentListener` or `ActionListener` (for Enter key pressed). 2) You have to add your table to the scroll pane's view port just once. If you want to update the table just work with its table model, either adding / updating / removing rows or by changing the whole table model through `table.setModel(...)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this section of code:

```
connection c = new connection();
DefaultTableModel T;
T= c.returndata("Select * From medrec Where student_no=?");
```

Specifically the 3rd line.  If you open the `connection` class (which you haven't shown the code for) and find the method `returndata` you should see that it will have the following line of code:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");
```

This is telling you that you haven't provided the necessary code to execute this method.

Comment: hey, uhm. i posted below the code in my connection, the one you were talking about. please help me. i'm desperate :'(